# nginx return localhost instead of domain in google oauth2 callback

Tags: nginx, google-oauth, reverse-proxy

I have web server with a reverse proxy to a `subdomain.example.com` using nginx to host a nodebb forum. Everything works fine until I try to set up google oauth 2 for nodebb. The redirect url is `http://localhost:4567/auth/google/callback` instead of `https://subdomain.example.com/auth/google/callback` so it causes `redirect_uri_mismatch` error when I try to login with google.

After a lot of searching and modify the nginx config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/subdomain.example.com` I got no lucks.
Here is my config file:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = subdomain.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```